# calendar code required

Tags: android

Where can I get code to generate a calendar which displays dates in a proper grid?
Or can I get code for a calendar app so that I can make a few changes to it? It will help ma save a lot of time.

Comment: Stackoverflow in general is not the place to just ask for source code you can integrate into your app. If you have a specific technical question with partially working code you can ask it here.

Answer (score 0):

See my question (Link below). If you plan to use the existing code and slap some stuff on it then you are in for disappointment. Nevertheless, it's a great experience looking at these codes. Try it out.

[How can I check out Android source code in Windows OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746407/how-can-i-check-out-android-source-code-in-windows-os)