# Getting the latest source

Tags: android, windows

How do I get the latest Android Open Source Project (AOSP) source on windows?

I do not want to build, interested in seeing core applications/services etc. to learn for use in my own application development.

Is Linux Virtual Machine the only way?

Comment: One option would be to browse the source online http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/

Comment: Already checked it out, seems incomplete.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746407/how-can-i-check-out-android-source-code-in-windows-os

Comment: For just browsing the source, I typically just use online resources (wastes less disk space).  Both the above GrepCode link and https://github.com/android are my go-to references.  I'm curious what you think is incomplete about them?

Comment: Well, I wanted to see default implementation of Keyboard what I assume resides in LatinIME, but, the GrepCode repository to it only contains `res`, no `src` folder.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is all contained in the com.android.inputmethod package; this is where the XML files in LatinIME point.  For instance, here's a link to the LatinKeyboard.java file: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.3_r1/com/android/inputmethod/keyboard/LatinKeyboard.java?av=f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle VM VirtualBox + Debian 6 and packages - `git`, `curl` results in a full-blow error-free repository synchronization.

I doubt there are better ways to get AOSP on Windows.

P.S. Debian can be replaced with any other Linux distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the site you're looking for is http://source.android.com/.

A number of interesting solutions appear here: [Where can I find Android source code online?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/449763/517561)

Comment: Been there, done that, git just throws out errors all the time about missing libraries and stuff for python.

Comment: Huh. I confess I didn't do it on Windows.