# how to download android open source project on windows machine?

Tags: android, android-source, repository

I can't install ubuntu on my office pc so i need to know is there any way to download android open source project on windows machine ? How ?
Thanks.

Comment: Please search first.  1 minute on Google gives you the answer.  Or look at the Related questions list over there ------------->

Comment: Windows is not a development OS because it does not have UNIX commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. this guide helped me to download it on windows:
http://blog.csdn.net/zhenwenxian/article/details/5780412
Done.

Answer (score 3):

You can use VirtualBox to install ubuntu as guest OS on your host windows machine. If you just want to browse code you can do that online on github, for any thing related to build you would require ubuntu (or other linux flavors).

Comment: The office PC is really slow, I can't use VirtualBox.

Comment: In that case use the option to browse source code online. Repo sync and build process can take a very long time (multiple hours) if your system is slow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746407/how-can-i-check-out-android-source-code-in-windows-os