# version control system of android for windows

Tags: android, svn, version-control, open-source

I want to checkout the android source code in windows 8. I am new to this, please any one help me out as to how can I download the android source code using what type of svn, client or server. I intend to view the revision history of android for research purpose.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746407/how-can-i-check-out-android-source-code-in-windows-os

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Tortoise SVN, its free and quite realiable. Also Eclipse has a plugin for svn handling